install racadm inside ubuntu container
I am trying to install racadm utility inside Ubuntu docker container, But it is failing. I am unable to view the logs completely. Is there any way i can do it by following any documentation. Please suggest. I am trying to install package srvadmin-idracadm7 and srvadmin-idracadm8.

https://linux.dell.com/repo/community/openmanage/
